# How can 6 workspaces be set sing Compiz?

Tags: configuration, workspaces

I want to set a desired number of workspaces in Ubuntu MATE 16.04, please help.

Comment: Do you currently have workspace switcher on the panel?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Install Compiz Config setting manager

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

And Workspaces is on **General Settings** named as **Desktop Size**

[Compiz manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIp8O.png)

[image: General view]

[image: Desktop Size tab to the right]

[image: Type in desired layout]

Answer (score 1):

Left click on the workspace switcher and select **Preferences**.

Comment: The answer is probably good, however you should improve it by adding a bit more details. Especially a screenshot would be a good idea. Moreover, I suggest you use *Italic*, not UPPERCASE, to write menu entries.

Comment: Helped me on Debian Mate (with right click on workspaces grid instead left click). I have no idea why I didn't noticed beforehand, that workspaces switch is an applet and can be configured that way...